# Can I get marriage/spouse visa for other countries if banned from UK?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, new-zealand

Long story short. Unfortunately, I was removed from the UK by the authorities. I understand that there is definitely going to be a ban on me to UK. Am I liable to get visa from other countries denied on the basis of that ban (such as New Zealand, Canada or the USA)?

My main concern is to find out whether New Zealand would ban me since my fiance is from New Zealand. Is there going to be an issue in getting a NZ visa because of a ban from the UK?

Comment: For what reason were you removed from the UK? Not all removals necessarily result in a ban. What is your citizenship?

Comment: Bitter UK enemies like Iran and Russia would easily give you visa. Did you overstay?

Comment: It depends if the other country has an equivalent to Article 8, but we don't know anything about marriage visas. Please use Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions for such questions.

Comment: According to UKBA I overstayed in the UK, I applied for business visa before my earlier visa got expired.. but my visa application was refused and I was given notice to go back to my home country India, but instead I went for tribunals, and judicial review etc.. I still have my case pending in the upper tribunal in UK but they removed me saying I do not have any legal stay in the country anymore.
Now I understand that I unintentionally breach the immigration law hence got removed but I am not sure if I am banned from UK or not? and whether I can get visa for other countries?

Answer (score 3):

Quite a lot of countries will **ask** you if you ever got removed, anywhere. Telling lies is (a) something which this board does not suggest, on principle, and (b) something whch gets you into even more trouble if you are caught.

- Do you want a visa for the purpose of getting married, or are you already married? That makes a difference.
- Of course the UK, the US and New Zealand are exchanging plenty of intelligence information. None of us can tell how much information they really exchange.

Comment: No.. I am not married yet I am 29 years old with clear police records and everything else as I am law abiding citizen. Actually one of my relative here suggested me a genuine newzealand resident female and want us get married. I am quite interested in her too but I dont want to start anything off there is no scope of me getting my visa issued for newzealand.

Comment: @Truth, if you are not yet married or in a stable relationship, you cannot get a family visa.

Comment: Yes I am not married yet with the person I intend to marry, although I will marry her in near future. Do we need to live in India for a year together? as it might be difficult for her to live here as she works there in newzealand..

Comment: @Truth, that question should be asked on Expatriates.SE.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a visa. Of course the UK ban might make it tougher since they ask questions on the visa forms but each application is judged on its own merit. For New Zealand, you have to provide solid proof of partnership & you must be of good character (produce a police clearance certificate). They might consider being banned as not of good character. But the UK only bans people for serious issues. Are you sure you were banned.

Comment: Note that your experience as a Portuguese (and hence EU) citizen would have been quite different than that of third-country citizens.

Comment: I understand. But he must've done something really serious to be banned.

Comment: No. Again that would be true for EU citizens, not for others.

Comment: @jordy .. I overstayed in UK hence got removed. however never ever had my name got listed in any police records or any other organisation for any illegal activity or else. but I am not sure now UK police will provide me clearance from the UK police since i was removed form the UK.